# How to unit test my java method which uses file locks?

Tags: java, unit-testing, locking, nio

Suppose I have the following code:

```java
public boolean canLock(Path path) throws IOException {
    try(FileChannel byteChannel = FileChannel.open(path);
        FileLock lock = byteChannel.tryLock()) {
        return lock != null;
    }
}
```

Of course this code is somewhat useless it's just here to illustrate the problem as compact as possible.

Now I want to unit test this method: I want to test that the result is false if the file is locked by another process. Something along the lines of this:

```
public void canLock_returnsFalse_ifFileIsLocked() {
  // setup
  Path tmpPath = createTmpPath();
  FileLock lock = lock(tmpPath);
  
  // execution
  boolean actual = canLock(tmpPath);
  
  // evaluation
  assertFalse(actual);
}
```

Now here comes the problem: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29) says:

> [tryLock()] returns null if the lock could not be acquired because another program holds an overlapping lock

and

> throws OverlappingFileLockException - If a lock that overlaps the requested region is already held by this Java virtual machine, or if another thread is already blocked in this method and is attempting to lock an overlapping region of the same file

This means the behaviour significantly differs if the lock was created by my own process and thus my unit test has a problem. How do I create a lock from a different process in a way which is generally acceptable for unit tests (portable, reliable, fast, simple).

Comment: Minus Voter, please provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use JMockit or PowerMock to mock the call to `FileChannel.open` so that it returns a mocked FileChannel.

[JMockit mock static method](http://binkley.blogspot.com/2011/07/jmockit-and-static-methods.html)

Comment: agree with usage of JMockit (to mock static API), however the actual Line of code which is playing role in this case is tryLock(). Is it not good just to mock tryLock as only null check decides the results for this API.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you want to test `canLock(...)`. In that case you simply mock FileChannel.
Refer this for Mockito example : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Updated :
In the above scenario Using JMockit (as answered by John B) is preferred as it is required to mock a static API which is not there in Mockito. However Mockito is worth learning :)